Must "modim anachnu lach" be said in Hebrew?
Prayers can be recited in any language, with a few exceptions.  I remember hearing that one these exceptions is the line מוֹדִים אֲנַחְנוּ לָךְ (we are thankful to you) in the Amidah.  It must be said in Hebrew while bowing.  Is this correct and what is the reference?

What is your source that anything in the siddur must be said in Hebrew? Furthermore, using a language you understand will make prayer more meaningful to the person who says it keeping in the definition of prayer which is the service of the heart

@Dude Birkas kohanim is in the siddur and has to be said in Hebrew

I have upvoted the question because I consider it to be a useful question. Just because the answer is "no" does not mean that the question is not useful.

Why would it be different than Shmone Esrei itself, which can be said in any language?

Mishnah Sotah 7:2 lists certain prayers which must be said in Hebrew.
וְאֵלּוּ נֶאֱמָרִין בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ. מִקְרָא בִכּוּרִים, וַחֲלִיצָה, בְּרָכוֹת וּקְלָלוֹת, בִּרְכַּת כֹּהֲנִים, וּבִרְכַּת כֹּהֵן גָּדוֹל, וּפָרָשַׁת הַמֶּלֶךְ, וּפָרָשַׁת עֶגְלָה עֲרוּפָה, וּמְשׁוּחַ מִלְחָמָה בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁמְּדַבֵּר אֶל הָעָם:
Of the prayers listed only בִּרְכַּת כֹּהֲנִים is part of our services today. Neither מוֹדִים אֲנַחְנוּ לָךְ nor any other part of the amidah is required to be said in Hebrew. Indeed Sotah 7:1 lists prayers which can be said in any language
אֵלּוּ נֶאֱמָרִין בְּכָל לָשׁוֹן, פָּרָשַׁת סוֹטָה, וּוִדּוּי מַעֲשֵׂר, קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע, וּתְפִלָּה, וּבִרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, וּשְׁבוּעַת הָעֵדוּת, וּשְׁבוּעַת הַפִּקָּדוֹן:
and that list includes the amidah (referred to as as well as וּתְפִלָּה) as well as the Shema and Bircat HaMazon.
For more on Modim see this article https://outorah.org/p/78474/ Modim d’Rabanan by Rabbi Ari Enkin.

Thanks.  I knew that Mishnah, but wondered if a custom developed to say Modim in Hebrew.  I definitely heard it from a reliable source many years ago -- don't remember where.
